# Creating a data-entry Form with multitable Query

Tags: ms-access

I have a form in my Access Database that is used for students to scan their badge and log in.  If their badge hasn't been registered, the form just allows them to enter their information.  I'm running into a problem where I'm using a Query that pulls their badge number from the previous form (which is inserted into a table temp) and compares it to the table with their information on it.

The problem I'm running into is that when I do this, I can't edit the information in the form, nor can I add more to entries, and when I separate the query and try to just pull from the table externally 
(`BadgeNumber = [temp]![T2]`)
it just pulls up a messagebox asking for the value.

[image: Example of Database]

Does anyone have any suggestions for accomplishing this?

Comment: `[temp]![T2]` i's not a valid reference to your table. Use a Dlookup: `=DLookup("[T2]", "temp")` assuming there is only ever one row in the temp table. The message box is probably titled "Enter Parameter" because Access will replace the bad table reference with a parameter value due to syntax, and will look for matches based on the input value instead of looking in the table like a Dlookup will.

Comment: Can I use this in the query?

Comment: Wait, I just gave terrible advice.

Comment: Why don't you just `INNER JOIN` your temp table on [BadgeNumber]?

Comment: Tried, it said Join is not supported.

Comment: If you check the datatype in your temp table, is it a long int?

Comment: Yes it is a Long Integer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125379/discussion-between-christopher-d-and-skathix).

Comment: Open the form with the table but set a filter to open it with the specific BadgeNumber you want to change.  If it's a new record, simply assign the default value to the BadgeNumber.